# What is a good algorithm and a data structure for rearrangement of items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Let's say I have some items, every item has a sequence - lesser sequences means items are above. An item can have a dependency/dependencies on other items. Also, an item can have dependables - i.e. some other items might depend on it. The below item list(i have used an associated array here) lists the items - the property 'dep' of each item lists dependencies and dependables.

```
var dependencyDict = {
  item1: {dependsOn: [], dependable: ['item3']},
  item2: {dependsOn: [], dependable: []},
  item3: {dependsOn: ['item1'], dependable: ['item4']},
  item4: {dependsOn: ['item3'], dependable: []}
}

var itemList  = {
  item1: {
    name: 'item1',
    seq: 1,
    dep: dependencyDict['item1']
  },
  item2: {
    name: 'item2',
    seq: 2,
    dep: dependencyDict['item2']
  },
  item3: {
    name: 'item3',
    seq: 3,
    dep: dependencyDict['item3']
  },
  item4: {
    name: 'item4',
    seq: 4,
    dep: dependencyDict['item4']
  }
}
```

According to the above, items in the order of their sequence are so:

```
item1
item2
item3
item4
```

My goal is to reorder the items i.e. change sequence(if possible) so that dependencies are intact.

Validation: an item can move only if dependencies remain intact: i.e.

- an item can depend only on items that are above it i.e. their sequence is less than item's sequence
  and vice verse i.e.
- an item can have items as dependents only if the items are below the item i.e. their sequences are greater than item's sequence

For example, if I say move(item3, 2) - I am asking to move item3 to position 2 so that new item list should be so:

```
{
  item1: {
    name: 'item1',
    seq: 1,
    dep: dependencyDict['item1']
  },
  item2: {
    name: 'item2',
    seq: 3,
    dep: dependencyDict['item2']
  },
  item3: {
    name: 'item3',
    seq: 2,
    dep: dependencyDict['item3']
  },
  item4: {
    name: 'item4',
    seq: 4,
    dep: dependencyDict['item4']
}
```

notice the change of sequences

But if I say move(item3, 1), it will not, because item3 depends on item1 - if it moves to position 1, item1 will go to position 2 which invalidates the rule that the item can depend only on the items that are above it.

My code is in working condition but I have used more if-elses than a proper algorithm

Flexibility: itemlist can be put in any data structure and any algorithm can be used

Comment: *above/below* are not terms which are applicable on objects.

Comment: where do you know, that **item3** rely on **item1**?

Comment: "an item can depend only on items that are above it i.e. their sequence is less than item's sequence and vice verse i.e.

items can depend on an item only if the items are below the item i.e. their sequences are greater than item's sequence" - feels like these 2 statements contradict each other, could you rephrase them?

Comment: "if I say move(item3, 12) " - what does 12 mean?

Comment: i updated the question and corrected my mistake

Comment: What you probably want is a [dependency graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_graph) to encode the dependencies between your items. When you want to move an item, you can check that the resulting order is valid by iterating through your ordered list and marking each item in the graph, checking each time that all of its parents have already been marked.

Comment: Do you really need to store the `seq` value for every item? What is the use case where you really need to know an exact sequence number for a certain item? Isn't it enough to know for a given pair of items, which one comes before the other?

Comment: I actually work with ```seq``` but we can assume the order of the data structure as the sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- If your data is large with many dependencies, it may be more efficient to use a `Set` for registering the dependencies instead of an array.
- Eliminate one of `dependsOn` or `dependable`, as one can be derived from the other
- Don't store `seq`, but just rely on the index an item has in an array. True, this means you have to scan an array with `indexOf`, but on the other hand you'll not have to make updates on all the `seq` properties involved in a move.
- Use zero-based indexes, instead of positions starting at 1.

Here is a `class` implementation of the data structure I'd propose.

```js
class OrderedGraph {
    constructor(pairs) {
        this._dep = new Map;
        this._order = [];
        if (pairs) for (let [item, dependsOn] of pairs) this.add(item, dependsOn);
    }
    add(item, dependsOn=[]) {
        for (let ref of dependsOn) if (!this._dep.has(ref)) throw ref + " not found";
        this._dep.set(item, new Set(dependsOn));
        this._order.push(item);
    }
    move(item, toIdx) {
        let fromIdx = typeof item === "number" ? item : this._order.indexOf(item);
        if (fromIdx < 0) throw "not found: " + item
        if (typeof item === "number") item = this._order[item];
        let dep = this._dep.get(item);
        let ok = fromIdx > toIdx
            ? !this._order.slice(toIdx, fromIdx).some(it => dep.has(it))
            : !this._order.slice(fromIdx+1, toIdx+1).some(it => this._dep.get(it).has(item));
        if (ok) this._order.splice(toIdx, 0, ...this._order.splice(fromIdx, 1));
        return ok;
    }
    indexOf(item)  { return this._order.indexOf(item) }
    includes(item) { return this._dep.has(item) }
    * values()     { yield * this._order }
    [Symbol.iterator]() { return this.values() }
}

// Example use
let data = new OrderedGraph([
    ["item1", []],
    ["item2", []],
    ["item3", ["item1"]],
    ["item4", ["item3"]]
]);

// Some actions on the data object:
console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(data)));
console.log("success moving 'item3' to 0? ", data.move("item3", 0));
console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(data)));
console.log("success moving 'item3' to 1? ", data.move("item3", 1));
console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(data)));
console.log("success moving 'item3' to 1? ", data.move("item3", 1));
console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(data)));
console.log("success moving 'item3' to 2? ", data.move("item3", 2));
console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(data)));
console.log("index of 'item3': ", data.indexOf("item3"));
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks great.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the dependencies with their index of the wanted new node list.

```js
function move(node, position) {
    var nodes = Object.keys(itemList).sort(({ seq: a }, { seq: b }) => a - b);

    nodes.splice(position - 1, 0, ...nodes.splice(itemList[node].seq - 1, 1));

    var valid = nodes.every((n, i) =>
            dependencyDict[n].dependsOn.every(m => nodes.indexOf(m) <= i) &&
            dependencyDict[n].dependable.every(m => nodes.indexOf(m) >= i)
        );

    console.log(valid);
    if (valid) nodes.forEach((node, i) => itemList[node].seq = i + 1);
    console.log(nodes);
    console.log(itemList);
}

var dependencyDict = {
        item1: {dependsOn: [], dependable: ['item3']},
        item2: {dependsOn: [], dependable: []},
        item3: {dependsOn: ['item1'], dependable: ['item4']},
        item4: {dependsOn: ['item4'], dependable: []}
    },
    itemList  = {
        item1: { name: 'item1', seq: 1, dep: dependencyDict['item1'] },
        item2: { name: 'item2', seq: 2, dep: dependencyDict['item2'] },
        item3: { name: 'item3', seq: 3, dep: dependencyDict['item3'] },
        item4: { name: 'item4', seq: 4, dep: dependencyDict['item4'] }
    };

move('item3', 1);
move('item3', 2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```